# Updating the UI from a background thread in Android

Tags: android

Edit: It was suggested that it would be helpful to add my code so, my AsyncTask code is now pasted below...

I'm just learning Android and I have a UI with a few buttons. I want to animate the UI, changing the color of the buttons, in a sequence.

I shouldn't do that from the main thread of course, and it doesn't work anyway. The code manipulating the UI runs but the UI doesn't update until the end of the sequence.

So I created a thread and tried to run through the sequence from a background thread however, I would get an error trying to manipulate the UI components from the background thread. Only the main thread can touch the UI components.

Then I discovered AsyncTask. What I figured was, I could run through the sequence in doInBackground(). Every time I needed to update the UI I'd call publishProgress() which would cause onProgressUpdate() to be called from the main thread so I could access UI components without error.

Every time I call publishProgress() I would follow it with a SystemClock.sleep(500) to let time pass until the next animated UI update.

What I found though was that doInBackground() would run through the 4 UI state changes in about 2 seconds (500 ms each) but the UI would not update with each call to publishProgress(). Instead doInBackground() completes and then onProgressUpdate() is called 4 times in a row.

From the description, publishProgress & onProgressUpdate are designed to update a progress bar as doInBackground cranks through some longish running task so, obviously, onProgressUpdate must execute multiple times before doInBackground  completes, right?

Am I missing something?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void startGame(View view) {
    MyTask task = new MyTask();
    task.doInBackground();
}


class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    private int current_int;


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        this.current_int = 1;
        Log.e("doInBackground","light up button "+this.current_int);
        publishProgress();
        SystemClock.sleep(500);
        this.current_int = 2;
        Log.e("doInBackground","light up button "+this.current_int);
        publishProgress();
        SystemClock.sleep(500);
        this.current_int = 1;
        Log.e("doInBackground","light up button "+this.current_int);
        publishProgress();
        SystemClock.sleep(500);
        this.current_int = 2;
        Log.e("doInBackground","light up button "+this.current_int);
        publishProgress();
        SystemClock.sleep(500);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... voids) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(voids);
        Log.e("onProgressUpdate","Updating button "+this.current_int);

        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        if (this.current_int==1){
            btn1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light));
            btn2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark));
        } else {
            btn2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light));
            btn1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to answer this question without the code you are trying to run. However, you shouldn't be calling sleep on the UI thread. The background thread is going to continue to run. You could possibly call `Thread.sleep()` in `doInBackground()` after calling `publishProgress()` to allow the UI to update and pause the background task while it updates.

Comment: I added my AsyncTask code. I thought my approach was likely the problem and not my code, so I described my approach. I did not call sleep on the UI thread, I called it in doInBackground() as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference : An Asynctask presents a systematic way to transition from main thread (calling thread) to the new thread (called thread). The *onPreExecute()* and *onPostExecute()* methods execute on the *calling* thread and the *doInBackground()* is the actual method executing on the new thread. Doing UI updates on main thread will hence lead to exception if done from *doInBackground()* method.

Your core background logic should hence be placed in the *doInBackground()* method.

If you want to update UI from background thread (Asynctask or otherwise), you can do it using this :

```
YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
          //UI update operations here
    }
});
```

Comment: My core background logic IS in doInBackground(). From doInBackground I call publishProgress() so that onProgressUpdate() will be called on the UI thread. I sleep immediately after calling publicProgress() so that there is time for the UI thread to call onProgressUpdate() but it's never called until doInBackground() exits.

Comment: Maybe you need share a boolean variable between threads and stall the background thread until the UI operations completes.. so that doInBackground() does not exit prematurely

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Handler` for this,

```
public class TestClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    boolean isRunning = true; //set false after executing UI logic.
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        YourFunctionToUpdateUI();
        return null;
    }
    public void YourFunctionToUpdateUI()
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (isRunning) {
                    try {
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // your code to update the UI.
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //handle exception
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems overly complicated and not like any example I've seen. It seems to me you're creating 3 nested threads. AsyncTask already provides at least two methods that get called from the UI thread.

Comment: Which two methods from UI thread? You just needs to call execute() of AsyncTask from your Activity and onPostExecute() set isRunning = false.

Comment: Just looked it up, there are three methods i AsyncTask that are called from the UI thread: onPreExecute(), onPostExecute() and onProgessUpdate(). I've verified this to be true because I can access my UI components from onProgressUpdate() without error. The problem is, all my calls to publishProgress() appear to queue up until doInBackground() exits

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. The problem is, I'm creating an AsyncTask and then calling doInBackground() directly, from my main thread instead of calling execute() which creates the background thread